# How can I find default colors for a given Android Theme?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme, android-dialogfragment

I am using the AppCompat.NoActionBar theme.  I'd like to know how to find the default colors for EditText lines and the Titles in DialogFragments.  These defaults look like a teal color and I am also wondering if they are the same color or different.  Is there an Android resource that lists out default colors by platform version?

Here is the themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>

</style>

    <style name="FloatingLabel" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance" >
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorFlLabelActivated</item>
</style>

...
```

[image]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example..." >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example..."
         >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example..."
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
         />
    </activity>

</application>
```

colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<color name="colorPrimary">#357EC7</color>
<color name="colorHint">#C0C0C0</color>
<color name="colorFlLabelActivated">#357EC7</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: EditText line color is the accentColor you set in your theme.

Comment: Do you mean the colorPrimary?  Because I have not set accentColor.  See above for themes.xml file.

Comment: If you don't set colorAccent it will take default color. You have to set 3 colors to make your theme: colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent.

Comment: In first comment there's wrong name, it should be colorAccent not accentColor.

Comment: I understand about having to set 3 colors.  But I am trying to find out the RGB color value that the default (the #Hex value) is currently using.  For example, see above.  I will edit to show the default color for the EditText line.

Comment: If you want to change the default color then you have to override it by defining colorAccent in your Theme where you override colorPrimary.

Comment: Right so what color do I use if I want to make my Floating Label color be the exact color of the default color that the OS is using for EditTexts?  I don't want to change the default, I want to use it!  But I don't know what the #Hex number is for the default color.

Comment: It's also the same colorAccent. Just add it in your theme and you will notice it.

Comment: So if set <item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item> then the #Hex of "FFFFFF" will set the colorAccent to white.  But I want the default color already being used and I don't know how to find out that default color blue.  The default blue line under the text "Do" is shown above.

Comment: From your photo in your question it doesn't look like you are applying Material Theme at all. That's an EditText view from Holo theme. Make sure you are not applying old theme to your Activity/View.

Comment: How would I tell?  I showed the themes.xml file that I am using above.  In the Manifest file I am using android:themse="@style/AppTheme".

Comment: Post your activity layout file, manifest file where you declare activity and complete theme.

Comment: The activity file is 806 lines long.  It sets up the EditTexts and uses "setContentView" for the layout file.

Answer (score 4):

goto to your android sdk and follow the path
\sdk\platforms\android-22\data\res\values\colors.xml
this contains the color code for all the items of the default theme

platform android-22 folder name can be different depending upon which platform tools you have installed for your sdk

Comment: Thank you.  But I am trying to determine the colors that are showing up by default. I want to use the default colors for other things like Floating Labels but I don't know how to get the default colors.

Answer (score 1):

As such there is no theme wise documentation but you might find following links useful and interesting.

**For Theme Styling**

- Look at this documentation [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

**For Details on Themes and its Components**

- Please see this [R.style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html)

**For Colour Details and Designing**

- See This [Color palette ,UI color application ,Themes](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#) or you might want to have look at this [Designing in Android](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.  But there has to be a way to find out what the OS is using for defaults.